# Attempting to cache HttpClient Request in Angular but seeing unresolved variables

Tags: angular, caching, promise, rxjs

I pretty much copied the code below from the [Angular HttpClient Docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#caching)

The reason I want to cache HttpClient GETS is because the site makes multiple GET requests to an endpoint but the data only changes once a day. So I'm thinking I could just cache the requests and save some space/time. I do have a browser cache setup on my nginx server, but that doesn't cache client requests, correct?

It's telling me, isCachable, get and put are unresolved. Am I missing an import somewhere or is there something else?

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpHeaders, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import {of} from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class RequestCacheManager implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private cache: RequestCache) {
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    // continue if not cachable.
    if (!isCachable(req)) {
      return next.handle(req);
    }

    const cachedResponse = this.cache.get(req);
    return cachedResponse ?
      of(cachedResponse) : this.sendRequest(req, next, this.cache);
  }

  /**
   * Get server response observable by sending request to `next()`.
   * Will add the response to the cache on the way out.
   */
  sendRequest(req: HttpRequest<any>,
              next: HttpHandler,
              cache: RequestCache): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    // No headers allowed in npm search request
    const noHeaderReq = req.clone({headers: new HttpHeaders()});

    return next.handle(noHeaderReq).pipe(
      tap(event => {
        // There may be other events besides the response.
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          cache.put(req, event); // Update the cache.
        }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

I'm hoping to implement this to help cut down on the amount of client side time/requests and space neccasary for my App to function.

Comment: Seems you need to look at the full example: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/db3e65fb1786179930704868f578429e47c399bf/aio/content/examples/http/src/app/http-interceptors/caching-interceptor.ts

Comment: @R.Richards, that'd help -__- ... I'll take a look.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation at [angular.io/guide/http#caching](https://angular.io/guide/http#caching) doesn't currently give the full picture.

This [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20181018061241/https://nrempel.com/guides/angular-httpclient-httpinterceptor-cache-requests/) is helpful.

You need to implement the [RequestCache](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/d4b8b2440673049c58d51b0ae4afceb028d62cc0/aio/content/examples/http/src/app/request-cache.service.ts), called `RequestCacheWithMap` in the example (and the example also depends on a [MessageService](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/d4b8b2440673049c58d51b0ae4afceb028d62cc0/aio/content/examples/http/src/app/message.service.ts)).

Then you [provide the HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/guide/http#provide-the-interceptor) something like this:

```js
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MyInterceptor } from './http-interceptors/my-interceptor';
import { RequestCacheWithMap } from './services/request-cache.service';
import { MessageService } from './services/message.service';

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    RequestCacheWithMap,
    MessageService,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MyInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: People looking for the blogpost, which is currently not available anymore, can find it at the [web archive here](https://web.archive.org/web/20181018061241/https://nrempel.com/guides/angular-httpclient-httpinterceptor-cache-requests/)